# I need to swap element in matrix using function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, matrix

I want to create a function that takes a matrix as an argument and does the following:

1. Swaps the first and last elements in each row
2. Swaps the 2nd and last line
3. Returns the modified matrix

I suppose it should be made using indexes but I don't understand how exactly.

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9], ['a','b','c','d']
def fun(matrix):
    i = 0 
    j = 0
    for i in matrix[i][j]:
         # for the 1st task
            matrix[i][0] = matrix[i][-1]
            matrix[i][-1] = matrix[i][0]
        # for the 2d task
        if i = 1:
            matrix[1][j]= matrix[-1][j]
            matrix[-1][j] = matrix[1][j]
    return matrix[i][j]

print(change(matrix))
```

What is incorrect?

Comment: Your matrix is not a matrix since its rows have different sizes. This complicates things. Is that intentional?

Comment: right, it was a given task

Comment: I'm not comfortable doing your homework for you, so I'd rather give you some general advice. You should look into [how loops work in python](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/), as well as understand your data structure. You don't seem to understand what your matrix looks like and how to access its elements properly. Once you understand these two things, you should be able to complete your task on your own.

Comment: it's not a homework actually, it's for self study and I'm trying to understand how it should be made cause we spent little time about it...

Comment: I suggest you back away from the Python code and describe **in words** the steps you need to acomplish each of the 3 tasks.

Comment: I also suggest you look at using the slice feature on lists, to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to achieve this?

Original matrix:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Changed matrix:

```
[3, 2, 1]
['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
[9, 8, 7]
[6, 5, 4]
```

If yes, then this would be code:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], ['a','b','c','d']]

def display(matrix):
  for row in matrix:
    print(row)
  print()

# displaying original matrix
print("Original matrix: \n")
display(matrix)

def swapElements(matrix):
  for row in matrix:
    row[0], row[len(row) - 1] = row[len(row) - 1], row[0]

def swapLines(matrix):
  matrix[1], matrix[len(matrix) - 1] = matrix[len(matrix) - 1], matrix[1]

def doAllswaps(matrix):
  swapElements(matrix)
  swapLines(matrix)
  return matrix

# displaying changed matrix
print("Changed matrix: \n")
display(doAllswaps(matrix))
```